# How to calculate Tab Bar height in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a page with a player that has a height of 1/3 of the screen height. Under the channels, there are multiple channels inside a scroll view. I am trying to set the height of the scroll view section exactly from bottom of the player to bottom of the page. I tried to set it to (screen height - (playerheight) - (navigation bar height) - (tabbed bar height)). But the problem is that the tabbed bar height changes from device to device. I tried the following code:

```
.frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height) - ((UIScreen.main.bounds.height) * 2/6) - (geometry.safeAreaInsets.top + geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom ) )
```

But it looks like geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom does not contain the tabbed bar height. So is there any way to calculate it in SwiftUI or is there any other way to achieve a similar appearance?

I just want to place scrollview that contains the channels exactly between player and tab bar for all screen sizes.

[image: sample design]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically detect Tab Bar or TabView height in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969911/programmatically-detect-tab-bar-or-tabview-height-in-swiftui)

Comment: The question has already been answered, though I think the following solution is much simpler. In the initializer of your app (or any View you want) you can create a UITabBarController object and then access its size with UITabBarController().controller.tabBar.frame.size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just starting to look at SwiftUI, but... I'm under the impression `GeometryReader` should handle this for you.

Give this a try:

```
struct Tab1View: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("Top == 1/3 height")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height / 3.0, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.5))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .border(Color.yellow)
                Text("Bottom == 2/3 height")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height * 2.0 / 3.0, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.init(red: 0.5, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .border(Color.yellow)
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
                   height: geometry.size.height,
                   alignment: .topLeading)
        }
    }

}
struct Tab2View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
    }
}

struct MyTabView: View {
    var body: some View {

        TabView {
            //Text("The content of the first view")
            Tab1View()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            //Text("The content of the second view")
            Tab2View()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyTabView()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

and, auto-adjusted to TabBar height when rotated:

[image]

---

**Edit**

After some more investigation, it looks like `ScrollView` can size itself to fill available space, so we only need to set the height on the top view.

Here's a modified example:

```
struct MyItemView: View {
    var itemDesc = "Testing"
    var geoWidth: CGFloat = 100
    var body: some View {
            Text("\(self.itemDesc)")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(16.0)
                .frame(width: self.geoWidth, height: nil, alignment: .leading)
    }
}

struct Tab1View: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
                Text("Top == 1/3 height")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height * 1.0 / 3.0, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.5))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .border(Color.yellow)

                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach((1...20), id: \.self) {
                            MyItemView(itemDesc: "This is item \($0)", geoWidth: geometry.size.width)
                                .background(Color.init(red: 0.5, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1))
                                .border(Color.yellow)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nil, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct Tab2View: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("Top == 1/3 height")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height * 1.0 / 3.0, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.7))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .border(Color.yellow)
                Text("Bottom == 2/3 height")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height * 2.0 / 3.0, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.init(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.1))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .border(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MyTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Tab1View()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            Tab2View()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyTabView()
    }
}
```

and, new result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: setting the frame of VStack embedded in GeometryReader is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: Very possibly/probably. I started with getting the VStack to fill the height, thinking there’d be a “distribution: fill” setting like UIStackView. So, yeah.

Comment: @user3441734 - yep... quick test shows setting `.frame` on the `VStack` is not needed.

Comment: @user3441734 - as I mentioned, I have ***just started*** looking at SwiftUI, so forgive any obvious mistakes. I've edited my answer with implementation of a scroll view for the lower 2/3 space.