# How to get height of a tabBar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to get the height of a tabBar in swiftUI however I am failing I know in swift we would do something like :

```
extension UITabBarController{

    func getHeight()->CGFloat{
        return self.tabBar.frame.size.height
    }

    func getWidth()->CGFloat{
         return self.tabBar.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent in SwiftUI?

Comment: yes it does Thank you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969911/programmatically-detect-tab-bar-or-tabview-height-in-swiftui/60136275#60136275 For wot do you need tab bar height?