# SwiftUI NavigationBar height

Tags: height, swiftui, navigationbar

How to get current NavigationBar height? In UIKit we could get

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
```

but can't find anything for SwiftUI...

Comment: The approach can be the same as for TabBar in [Programmatically detect Tab Bar or TabView height in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972635/12299030)

Comment: TY, this is the answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on this post (thanks to [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi)): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972635/12299030

```
struct NavBarAccessor: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var callback: (UINavigationBar) -> Void
    private let proxyController = ViewController()

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavBarAccessor>) ->
                              UIViewController {
        proxyController.callback = callback
        return proxyController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavBarAccessor>) {
    }

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController

    private class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var callback: (UINavigationBar) -> Void = { _ in }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            if let navBar = self.navigationController {
                self.callback(navBar.navigationBar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then we can call this from any View:

```
.background(NavBarAccessor { navBar in
      print(">> NavBar height: \(navBar.bounds.height)")
                // !! use as needed, in calculations, @State, etc.
 })
```

Comment: This works fine. But don't use it on the NavigationView, since navigation controller will be nil then. Also, the `typealias` in the  `NavBarAccessor` can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @yoprst 's response, rather than configure calculations and @State variables, you could also return a `View` to insert directly into the hierarchy:

```
struct NavigationBarAccessor: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var callback: (UINavigationBar) -> (AnyView)
    private let proxyViewController = ProxyViewController()

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationBarAccessor>) -> UIViewController {
        self.proxyViewController.callback = callback
        return proxyViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationBarAccessor>) {
    }

    private class ProxyViewController: UIViewController {
        var callback: ((UINavigationBar) -> AnyView)?

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
                _ = self.callback?(navigationBar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
VStack {
    NavigationBarAccessor { navigationBar in
        Spacer()
            .frame(height: navigationBar.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: a generic constraint would be more preferable rather than AnyView using