# TabBarItem how to change icon color

Tags: swift, swiftui

The default color of inactive `TabBarItem` icon is gray

[image]

How can I change the default color?

XCode 14.2
SwiftUI 4.x.x

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color with appearance settings:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  init() {
     UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
  }

  var body: some View {
     ...
  }
}
```

otherwise check another approach shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727573/4977439

Comment: Is there no any solution with the modifier?

Comment: There is no OOTB modifier, but you can build your own based on the solution in the provided link, or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969911/programmatically-detect-tab-bar-or-tabview-height-in-swiftui/59972635#59972635, but that's basically wrapper over UIKit component to track rendering event and change color dynamically. I would recommend following the Appearance approach as you won't have any issues with runtime.

Comment: What is the recommended approach?

Comment: the recommended approach here in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

If that is systemImage, set the icon in systemName, then there is a mac app called SF Symbols where you can change the color to the emoji you want!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).