# SwiftUI - can you control the TabView attributes?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabbar, tabview

I have moved my tabBar over to a TabView in the SwiftUIifiication of my app.

I want to be able to deactive various Tabs depending on where you are in the app. In UI this code would be along the lines of:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].isEnabled = false
```

Is this even possible in SwiftUI?

Comment: Here is possible approach to disable tab bar directly from UITabBar:https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727573/4667539

I think this will work.

Comment: You can’t do it like UIKit does it but depending on your setup you can filter, use conditionals, etc.

Comment: Following that approach. Many thanks.