# UIView hidden by TabView

Tags: swiftui

I have tried to include TabView in my SwiftUI, after inclusion, I found that the bottom of the other UIView is being covered.

I have tried to use GeometryReader in each of my UIView, so that it get the maximum space. However, I found that it is still covered by the TabView unless I try to hide it. Any method to get the space only occupied by the screen (visible area, not include the tab bar at the bottom)?

Comment: The idea is to get tab bar height (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972635/14733292) and remove it from the main view height.

Comment: Would you provide demo code for your problem?