# Swiftui: How to add Accessibility Identifier on navigationTitle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, uikit

How can we add the `Accessibility Identifier` to NaviagationTitle Text. I know for buttons/text/Image/stack views we can use `.accessibility(identifier: “some_identifier”)`.

```
struct SomeView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
         Text("Title Text")
           .accessibility(identifier: "title")
           }
           .navigationTitle("title") //How to add accessibilityIdentifier to Navigation bar title?
           //.navigationTitle(Text("title").accessibility(identifier: "title"))
       }
   }
```

unable to add the modifier to `.navigationBarTitle(Text(“title”), displayMode: .inline)`. Accessibility Identifiers are required for XCUI automation testing.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible in SwiftUI using `.accessibility(identifier:)` - it might be worth submitting feedback to Apple.

However, you can still access the navigation bar by its identifier - just the default identifier is the text:

```
.navigationTitle("title")
```

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
assert(app.navigationBars["title"].exists) // true
```

---

Alternatively, you can try to access `UINavigationBar` using a helper extension (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972635/8697793)):

```
struct NavigationBarAccessor: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var callback: (UINavigationBar?) -> Void
    private let proxyController = ViewController()

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationBarAccessor>) -> UIViewController {
        proxyController.callback = callback
        return proxyController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationBarAccessor>) {}

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController

    private class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var callback: (UINavigationBar?) -> Void = { _ in }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            callback(navigationController?.navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access `UINavigationBar` from a SwiftUI view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("text")
                .navigationTitle("title")
                .background(
                    NavigationBarAccessor {
                        $0?.accessibilityIdentifier = "id123"
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the above example you set `accessibilityIdentifier` to the `UINavigationBar` itself and not to the title directly.