# How do I recreate the animated tab bar shown programmatically in Swift UI without storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabs, tabview

I'm trying to replicate the animated tab view bar at https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar  without storyboards for practice with Swift UI:

[Animated Tab Bar GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIRcd.gif)

I was looking through StackOverflow for solutions to recreate this pragmatically and was discouraged by the complex to the point it seemed to take a very long time (even without animation) to compile with Xcode becoming unresponsive at times (maybe I don't understand or was doing something wrong?).

From answer 3 ([Programmatically detect Tab Bar or TabView height in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969911/programmatically-detect-tab-bar-or-tabview-height-in-swiftui)):
"static var defaultValue: [CGRect] = []
// static func reduce(value: inout [CGRect], nextValue: () -> [CGRect]) {"

Basically two questions:

1. Is it even possible to make this completely in code with TabView in Swift UI: https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar?
2. Is Programmatic approach "better" than storyboards to make this tab view?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: and... take a look at this one [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is for coding specific issues; attempt some code and when you get stuck, post it and we'll take a look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.