# How can I add a 'pinned' view above a TabView's tabs?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

Using SwiftUI, how can I achieve something like the Apple Music app?
they have a now playing bar that is visible across all tabs. Is this something I can recreate using SwiftUI?

[image: music]

I have tried using overlay:

```
TabView {
    NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
        ContentView()
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                ViewFactory.viewForDestination(destination)
            }
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Home")
    }
    DownloadsView()
        .tabItem {
            Text("Downloads")
        }
}
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    MediaControlBar()
}
```

but the bar overlaps the tabs and does not adjust the content of the views

EDIT:

I am a bit closer with this custom implementation, but it will not let me switch views:

```
struct MyTabView: View {
    var items: [MyTabItem]
    @State var selectedItem: MyTabItem
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            selectedItem.view
            MediaControlBar()
            Picker("tabs", selection: $selectedItem) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
    }
    struct MyTabItem: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
        static func == (lhs: MyTabView.MyTabItem, rhs: MyTabView.MyTabItem) -> Bool {
            lhs.id == rhs.id
        }
        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(id)
        }
        let id = UUID()
        let view: AnyView
        let title: String
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see any customisation options that would work

Comment: You can build a completely custom tab bar and include anything in it

Comment: I've updated my question with my attempt to use overlay

Comment: Coincidentally, [I answered another question about putting things above the tab bar today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76685066/5133585).

Answer (score 1):

`Toolbar` is the perfect element for your needs. You can declare its placement as `.bottomBar` which means it will always stay attached to the `TabBar` and share its transparency. It also works correctly with `ScrollViews`:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Group {
            NavigationStack {
                Spacer()
                    .navigationTitle("Home")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("Home")
            }
            NavigationStack {
                Spacer()
                    .navigationTitle("Dowloads")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle")
                Text("Downloads")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                HStack {
                    Text("This is a toolbar")
                       .bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                    Image(systemName: "forward.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Toolbar in action 1]
[image: Toolbar in action 2]